# density pixels(dp) is not working fine for all resolutions

Tags: android, pixel

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkgray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/attenders"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Attenders" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:text="Send IM" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code but the dp is not working fine for all screen resolutions.
suggestions plz, plz tell me if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: please elaborate on "not working fine". how does it look like?

Comment: @Tahir...tahir have you seen my answer that i have given below.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey problem is that when i use dp for setting height or width of a button it does not gets fits to all resolutions i-e on small screens it looks big and on big screens it looks small, whereas i know that when we use dp for setting height and width of any component it automatically converts/adjusts according to screen resolution.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomer i have seen your answer but its not helpful

Comment: Ah, yes. The myth of dips. I'll add my answer below.

Comment: it will be helpful if u can please

Comment: @Tahir Have you tried setting minWidth and minHeight on your buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> problem is that when i use dp for setting height or width of a button
>   it does not gets fits to all resolutions i-e on small screens it looks
>   big and on big screens it looks small, whereas i know that when we use
>   dp for setting height and width of any component it automatically
>   converts/adjusts according to screen resolution

What I understand from this is that you thought using `dp` instead of `px` (or `in`, or `cm`) will magically work such that they will all have the same physical size on all devices, regardless of that device's density (ppi).

**That's not the case.**

dp, or dip, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension), is

> An abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen.
>   These units are relative to a 160 dpi (dots per inch) screen, on which
>   1dp is roughly equal to 1px.

A screen with more dpi (denser, meaning more pixels are packed into a square area of the screen), will essentially draw a physically smaller image compared to a screen that has 160dpi when tasked to draw the same, say, 100x100 dp image.

> When running on a higher density screen, the number of pixels used to
>   draw 1dp is scaled up by a factor appropriate for the screen's dpi.

**Solution**

There are two easy ways to have your app look proportionally the same on different screen sizes.

The first is to use different layout folders (layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, etc.). This technique is well-explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers). A much more recommended way would be to use different `style` values for each density, so you can still maintain one `layout` folder and refer to the styles instead for measurement. This can be done using the same technique, but instead you will have values-ldpi, values-mdpi, etc. This is useful for having standard sized UI elements across screen sizes.

The other way is to use `weights` all over your layout. Weights adjust automatically regardless of screen size of density. This will help a lot if you want, say, three columns that have varying width -- you can easily use weights to tell the layout that column A needs to occupy 40% of the available width of the screen, and B and C will have 30% each. This is useful for having a standard layout across screen sizes.

A clean-looking, nicely coded app will implement both.

Comment: oh thanks man that was really helpful. i can't voteup because it requires 15rep to voteup, sorry for that, but nice answer it cleared me everything.Thankyou

Comment: there you go, 23 rep.

Comment: Unfortunately this is problematic to get right in a GridLayout, where weights have no relevance at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is beacause you are giving fixed dimensions which can only be fit for a particular screen size which you are using. So try avoiding static dimensions and make use of match_parent,wrap_content and fill_parent so that you can get your layout fit for every screen size.

Comment: but when we use dp for setting height and width of any component it automatically adjusts its size according to screen resolution.

Comment: no it does not...using of match_parent,wrap_content and fill_parent adjusts the size automatically.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
read this article and you will get to know what dp exactly does

Comment: i have designed hundreds of complex layouts successfully so i dnt think that i need to read that.when you give a fixed height it does not adjusts its size but it looks smaller on bigger screen and vice versa.so use weights and match_parent,wrap_content or you can even use dimen file to give dimensions for different screen densities.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava  fill_parent is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: I know that but few people still use it,so that was for them.